# How do I remove extra space in my side bar?

Tags: css

I am trying to make a replica of taco bell's website just for fun and as a challenge, and the replica website is private so no one will see it, anyways I am trying to make a side bar, it went good so far until this extra space (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eck5L.jpg) appeared in the side bar, here is my css code (also I am a beginner):

```css
.nav {
    height: 84%;
    width: 150px;
    max-height: 84%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 137px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    min-width: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Please also add your HTML code.

Comment: We are not understanding your problem. please describe in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Try using display: inline-block it will work better since it will turm into  an inline element with block element properties but also make sure to fix the max height and max width stuff because they are probably what is causing that space.